# react native staging in android

Tags: android, react-native, staging, react-native-config

I am trying to get flavors or build variants running in android for my react-native project.

Via Schemes I got the same running on iOS, but Android does not want to follow. I guess something I am doing wrong.

Steps that I took so far *(all in a fresh project to test)*:

1. npm install react-native-config
2. created 3 files .env, .env.staging and .env.production
3. Added the following into the android/app/build.gradle:

> ```
>  project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
>   staging: ".env.staging",
>   production: ".env.production",
> ]
>
> apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
> ```

4. Added the flavours into the same file (suffix is commented out to not change the name -> hope that is not the problem):

> ```
> flavorDimensions "appType"
>         productFlavors {
>         staging {
>             dimension "appType"
>             applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
>             // resValue "string", "app_name", "Config Demo-Staging"
>         }
>         production {
>             dimension "appType"
>             applicationIdSuffix ".production"
>             // resValue "string", "app_name", "Config Demo"
>         }
>         }
> ```

5. Added the following scripts in the package.json:

> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "androidStagingDebug": "react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug",
>     "androidProductionDebug": "react-native run-android --variant=productionDebug",
>     "ios": "react-native run-ios",
>     "start": "react-native start",
>     "test": "jest",
>     "lint": "eslint ."
>   },
> ```

Now I want to start the app from Android Studio and just check via:

```
import config from 'react-native-config';
```

and respectively in a later function:

```
console.log(config)
```

whether I read the right file when choosing a build variant.

**Unfortunately it either does not load any or only debug. Any idea?!
Additionally in some variants it seems the app does not connect to metro..**

Comment: How do you launch the app ? As my concern, I don't use any script and launch it from Android studio by selecting the build variant.

Comment: actually I just run it from Android Studio not from the terminal - but was just following this https://ajaysidhu17.medium.com/configure-production-and-staging-environments-in-react-native-6c0d0faad034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build.gradle file seems ok.

Mine is slightly different though :

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    prod: "./environment/.prod",
    beta: "./environment/.beta",
    alpha: "./environment/.alpha",
]
```

Then :

```
flavorDimensions "default"

  productFlavors {
    prod {
        applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
    }
    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
    }
    alpha {
        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
    }
}
```

Like I said in a comment earlier, I don't use any script to launch the app, I just select the build variant in Android Studio.

Here's the resource I used:

https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-multiple-environments-on-react-native-for-ios-and-android-c43f3128754f

And here's an example project:

https://github.com/therealemjy/react-native-tuto-multiple-environments/tree/result

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: So what you mean is you did not put any script into the package.json?

Comment: Indeed, no script related to the flavoring

Comment: The code from the example somehow did it... I really do not know why. So thanks a lot, but I think there is still a lot to learn for myself :D

Comment: I had hard time doing that as well :) It was my pleasure to help

Comment: Interestingly I do not even use Flavours now. Maybe that is why?